# Excel Select Data 'Add' option isn't giving option to add both x and y values anymore

Tags: excel

Using Excel 2016. I want to add a second curve to an existing plot but when I right-click the existing plot and select the 'Select Data' option and then select the 'Add' option I get the following dialogue:

[Excel Edit Series Menu 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI1aD.png)

Notice I am unable to select a set of both x and y values. How come I don't get the following menu which allows me to select both x and y values?

[Excel Edit Series Menu 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeRRG.png)

Comment: Presumably the primary chart type is not XY scatter

Comment: Thanks. I changed plot type to a line type of plot since the marks were too big in the xy scatter and I couldn't find the old 'built-in' option to select mark size. I didn't realise doing so would not make it an xy plot anymore.